# Erlang interactions with COM objects

Tags: com, erlang

Does anyone know how to interact with COM objects using Erlang? I found comet library that allowed it, but it looks like this code is no longer present in OTP package.

I'm considering to write code in another language (like C++ or C#) and communicate with Erlang through ports but not sure if this approach is the most convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, `erl_com` (`comet`) is [not supported since R9B](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/doc/highlights.html).

> ## Comet, COM client for Erlang (REMOVED)
>
> The Comet application is removed from the product because we currently
>   have no resources to maintain it. We plan to make it available on the
>   Open Source site. It still works on Windows NT 4, but there are
>   problems on Windows XP.

We have 18.3 now (R18B03 in old version format). It was using a [linked_in driver](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) for communication. It is a quite efficient way to communicate with external code but [dangerous](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/overview.html#id56599).

> ### Warning
>
> A faulty linked-in driver causes the entire Erlang runtime system to leak memory, hang, or crash.

See [Interoperability Tutorial User's Guide](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html) for more details. There are four main options:

1. [Ports](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/c_port.html) - forked process communicating thru stdin/stdout.
2. [Port Drivers](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) (linked-in drivers) - like Ports but inside emulator memory space. Faster with great flow control but dangerous.
3. [C/Java Nodes](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/cnode.html) - Servers which are written in foreign language behaving like nodes in Erlang cluster. Uses Erlang Distribution Protocol.
4. [NIFs](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/nif.html) - Same reliability drawbacks as linked-in drivers but much simpler API.

Ports and C/Java Nodes are preferred way if reliability is in your concerns. NIFs are preferred when performance is most important. Linked-in drivers are legacy and for special use where NIFs API is not powerful enough.

And of course, you can communicate with servers using [Standard Protocols](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-7.3/doc/tutorial/overview.html#id60589).